# After Update, Insert Trigger not working on Update SQL Server VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, triggers

I am building a personal comic book database and am having an issue with one of my SQL Server triggers.

My main comic entry (tabbed) form has a combo box for cover prices.

When the user clicks submit and inserts a comic into the database (comic_books table) on the comics entry page, I have a trigger that adds the cover price the user entered to a separate table (comic_prices table.) if the entry does not exist. This is working just fine.

However, I have a second tab ('Edit Comic') where the user can update an already inserted comic which uses a simple update script.
The user is able to change or add a new cover price of said comic from this tab also.

The issue I am having is that when the user clicks the 'Update Comic' button from the 'Edit Comic' tab, this newly entered comic price is not being inserted in the comic_prices table if it does not exist. So it looks like my trigger is only firing on my insert script and not on my update script.
 Again, I have the trigger to only insert if the entry does not exist in the cover_prices table, otherwise it does nothing.

Please see my 'AFTER UPDATE, INSERT' trigger for this below and please let me know if you need any more information!
I appreciate any pointers or critiques!

```
DECLARE @cover_price varchar(50)
   select @cover_price = cover_price from comic_books        
    If exists (SELECT cover_price FROM comic_prices where cover_price = @cover_price )
  Begin
      Return
  End
  IF not EXISTS (SELECT cover_price FROM comic_prices where cover_price = @cover_price)   
   INSERT INTO comic_prices(cover_price)VALUES(@cover_price)
```

Comment: After two or so weeks, I finally figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 04/22/17
After two or so weeks, I finally figured it out!   I ended up making two separate triggers, one for the insert and another for the update. I kept the insert the same, however, the update looks like this:

```
DECLARE @publisher_name varchar(50)
    --declare @comic_id bigint
    select @publisher_name = inserted.issue_publisher from inserted
    select @comic_id = comic_id from comic_books
       If exists (select publisher_name from comic_publishers where publisher_name = @publisher_name)
  Begin
      return
  End
       IF not EXISTS (select publisher_name from comic_publishers where publisher_name = @publisher_name)
        INSERT INTO comic_publishers (publisher_name)VALUES(@publisher_name)
```

I needed to tell the trigger to look for the inserted publisher!